# Finding array sum in assembly x86_64

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am trying to write a function in assembly which finds the sum of an array consisting of 10 int elements. Everytime I run my program it shows me random numbers between 4195600 and 4195700. This is my function:

```
.section .data

iarr:

  .int 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9


  func:
    
  jmp ifAnw

  doAnw:

  addl (%rdi, %rcx, 4), %eax

  inc %rcx

  ifAnw:

  cmpq $10, %rcx

  jne doAnw

  ret
 

.globl main

main:

  movq $0, %rcx

  leaq iarr, %rdi

  call func
```

The rest is given to us by the prof, so my mistake should occur somewhere in between here. Can anyone please help me by telling me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You've changed an edit to fix your formatting, and made your code even less readable.

Comment: Do not try to use `esp` as a general purpose register. The only reason this does not crash is because `rcx` already starts at `10` so you don't even loop once. Also, you might want to zero `eax`.

Comment: my bad, I actually was trying something before I posted this. I have tried putting 0 as well but still the same.

Comment: Hint: what's the initial value of EAX before you `add` into it? Also, asking the caller to zero RCX for you makes no sense.  Asking the caller to put a length in RCX *would* make sense, and the function counts it down.  But hard-coding `10` into the function and requiring the caller to zero RCX for you is just leaving part of the work to every caller.  (You could justify it some if the loop condition `ifAnw` was the call target, but since you're using a `jmp` anyway at the start of the function, you should just initialize the registers you need initialized before entering the loop.)

Answer (score 1):

After some tries I realised what was wrong. Basically what I needed to do is to add `movl $0, %eax` at the beginning of the func function.

Here is the updated code:

```
  func:

  movl $0, %eax

  jmp ifAnw

  doAnw:

  addl (%rdi, %rcx, 4), %eax

  inc %rcx

  ifAnw:

  cmpq $10, %rcx

  jne doAnw

  ret
```

Comment: Like I commented earlier, zeroing RCX should be inside this function, not in main.  Your use of RCX as a loop counter is purely inside this function; it makes no sense to leave it up to the caller to initialize it for you.  You should put that zeroing instruction where it belongs, next to the one for EAX.